Cartridge size not known for bathtub faucet
I bought a new clawfoot tub and faucet at Tub King. There is no manuf/model that I can see and the booklet was thrown out by the installer 12 years ago. Today the business is closed
I am hearing there are 100’s of cartridge sizes?? Any advice would be helpful. It’s been leaking many years

I'll assume the faucet was for the bathtub not a telephone. :)

A picture of the faucet (and old cartridge) might really help you get answers,

Try removing the cartridge that is there and taking it to a good plumbing supply house. They may be able to match it.
